"Missing argument for parameter id" when calling apply in case class companion object
I'm trying to use a custom apply method in the companion object of a case class to generate a User instance without manually specifying an ID. The ID is supposed to be automatically generated using AtomicLong. However, I'm getting an error saying:
missing argument for parameter id of method apply in object User: (id: Long, email: String, login: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, password: String): User
Here's my case class and companion object:
case class User private(id: Long, email: String, login: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, password: String)

object User {
    private val seq = new AtomicLong

    def apply(email: String, login: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, password: String): User = {
        new User(seq.incrementAndGet(), email, login, firstname, lastname, password)
    }

    def mapperTo(id: Long, email: String, login: String, firstname: String, lastname: String, password: String): User = {
        new User(id, email, login, firstname, lastname, password)
    }
}

In my controller, I'm trying to create a User without specifying an ID:
def createUser = Action { implicit request: MessagesRequest[AnyContent] =>
      //lazy val usersTable = TableQuery[UserTable]
      val db = Database.forConfig("sqlite")
      val errorFunction = { (formWithErrors: Form[Data]) =>
        formWithErrors.errors.foreach { error =>
          println(s"Erreur dans le champ : ${error.key}, message : ${error.message}")
        }
        BadRequest(views.html.signup(formWithErrors))
      }

      val successFunction = { (data: Data) =>
        // This is the good case, where the form was successfully parsed as a Data object.
        val user = User.apply(email = data.email, login = data.login, firstname = data.firstname, lastname = data.lastname, password = data.password)
        val insertQuery = usersTable += user
        UserDatabase.db.run(insertQuery)
        Redirect(routes.HomeController.index()).flashing("info" -> "New user")
      }

      val formValidationResult = form.bindFromRequest()
      formValidationResult.fold(errorFunction, successFunction)
    }

But I get the error at the line where I try to create the User. It seems like Scala is looking for the id parameter, even though I want to use the apply method that generates it internally.
I also have a method mapperTo in the companion object to map data from the database, but this shouldn't affect the apply method.
What could be causing Scala to ask for the id when calling apply, and how can I fix this issue?

I copy pasted your User class with the companion object and I was able to use it in a main method. Also tried to use it in a dummy play project without the db objects and it works fine. No error at all. Each line I call the apply method it returns a new instance with the id incremented. Can't reproduce on my side. It works also in the example I created at scatsie. Is it possible to share a minimal reproducible example?

Which Scala version? Did you run a clean compile? Also, maybe just consider using a different name than apply
